# how to add space between edit and delete class in php something line (&nbsp)

Tags: php, html

```
                    <tbody>
                         <?php foreach($booklist as $book)

                         { ?>
                              <tr>
                                   <td><?php echo $book['bookid']; ?></td>
                                   <td><?php echo $book['bookname']; ?></td>
                                   <td><?php echo $book['author']; ?></td>
                                   <td><?php echo $book['price']; ?></td>
                               <td>
<a href="<?php echo site_url('home/edit/' . $book['bookid']); ?>" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
```

i want space between these edit and delete icons
    " class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">

```
//[i want to have a single space between these two icons][1]//
```

Comment: You can add pipe "|" between two <a> tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply print or add a space -

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('home/edit/' . $book['bookid']); ?>" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>  
&nbsp;     // print space here  
<a href="<?php echo site_url('home/delete/' . $book['bookid']); ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
```

You can also use `margin-left` or `padding-left` of `CSS` according to your need.

Answer (score 2):

Always try to avoid using html to effect the presentation, better to use CSS, such as

```
td a.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `&nbsp;` - but a better option would be to use CSS.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

but this is the tip on how to minimize typing the word "&nbsp"

you can use

```
str_repeat("&nbsp",10)
```

code above add 10 spaces

maybe this would help